# Gatsby develop options in production

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to get my head around what I can do with GatsbyJS. When you develop in GJS you get the dynamic compiling of your site, but when you publish you only get a static site. Is it possible to get the dynamic compiling in a production site so GSJ looks at a git or a directory for changes and automatically compile changes from markdown to blog posts and site pages? 
The appeal lies in the simplicity so a team can use systems like GitHub for writing and deploy within GitHub just by adding to the master branch. 
Do you know how to get this dynamic compile in GSJ or maybe in another NodeJS framework?

Answer (score 1):

Couple options here:

1. [Gatsby Cloud](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) - Free tier to test with, it will monitor GitHub commits and rebuild as necessary, then you push it to a host, CDN, etc..
2. Setup your own build pipeline with something like Travis or CircleCI (most complicated)
3. Setup something like this guide for [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/02/24/a-step-by-step-guide-gatsby-on-netlify/)